# Zend Url Helper.. not so helpful

Tags: zend-framework

I am having some problems with Zend Url helper. As far as I can see I am doing everything right according to the manual. My route is:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('client-portal/address-book/edit/:address_id',array('controller' => 'client-portal', 'action' => 'address-edit'));
$router->addRoute('client-portal-settings-address-edit', $route);
```

and I am calling it with a hardcoded value just so that I am not passing an empty value like this:

```
$this->url(array('address_id' => 3), 'client-portal-settings-address-edit', true);
```

but the output of the call is:

```
/client-portal/address-book/edit/:addressId
```

so no parameter substitution. Can anyone shine a light on this and help with why it is doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the 'Static' route type, which is for exact match URLs (i.e. ones that don't contain variables). Since your URL does contain variables, you probably want `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` instead:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'client-portal/address-book/edit/:address_id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'client-portal',
        'action' => 'address-edit'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('client-portal-settings-address-edit', $route);
```

Comment: Superb.. that fixed it. I knew it was something simple. It usually is with me. Thanks.